# SQL query MySQL to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, google-visualization

I have a problem to create an SQL statement

I have 2 tables :Teams and cups

```
table Teams :team id, team
table Cups:team_id, EuroCup, Worldcup
```

At the moment I have :

```
select t.team as Stats,sum(Eurocups) as Value
  from cups c 
    join team t
       on c.team_id=t.team_id
  where c.team_id = 3 or c.team_id=1
 group by t.team
```

which give me

```
Stats    Value
Spain     2
France    3
```

I wish to create sql query, that is comparing 2 different teams like:

```
Stats     Value1 Value2
Eurocups     2     3
```

All this for Google charts Stacked bar chart, that will take data from MySQL and converts to JSON, like

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Stats',   'Value1', 'Value2'],
['Eurocups',    2,       3     ],
['Worldcups',   1,       2     ]
```

]);

Comment: All you say seems correct. What's the question ?

Comment: I wish to create sql query, that is comparing 2 different teams like:

    Stats     Value1 Value2
    Eurocups     2     3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t.team as Stats,
(select sum(t1.Eurocups) from cups t1 where t1.team_id = 3) as Value1,
(select sum(t2.Eurocups) from cups t2 where t2.team_id = 1) as Value2
 from cups c 
join team t
   on c.team_id=t.team_id
where c.team_id = 3 or c.team_id=1
group by t.team
```